# Reverse Proxy to Report Server

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I have two windows server 2012 boxes hosted in Azure. one , has SSRS  Server installed, configured, and running properly. The other box has IIS Already hosting an application and it is running as it should.

Our intention, is to take advantage of SSRS web portal from our existing app. So, we Thought of Reverse proxy from IIS to reporting services web portal ( we are implementing this just internally ).

The intended behavior:
when someone enters a URL like this:

> ourdomain.com/folder_in_the_app/Reporting

We want to redirect this request to:

> databaseboxeWhereSSRSResides: 8321/Reports/

What we did:
we implemented Url rewrite and added this rule:

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy to Report Server" stopProcessing="True">
<match url="(.*)/Reportings" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="False" />
<action type="Rewrite" 
  url="http://databaseserver:port#1234/Reports/browse/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The error we get :

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL:

> /FolderinOurApp/Reportings

I have played a lot with it but no luck so far.

Any Help would be much appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of details missing. In order to troubleshoot this issue, I  would recommend you to use [Failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

You have used the words like **Reverse Proxy**, but haven't mentioned anything about using ARR.

Taking your scenario into consideration, Reverse Proxy looks to be an apt solution. You will have to install the ARR module on the Front-End server and use that to proxy request to your reporting server.

Use Web Platform Installer to install [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

To get started see this: [Creating a Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite for IIS](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis)

If you want to only redirect and not proxy the requests, then there are few checks that you need to perform:

- Is the DB url accessible from your Front-end Server
- Have you enabled FREB logs on the Reporting server to see where the failure is coming from?